# mask-image property is not working in Bracket

Tags: html, css

This code is working fine here but I'm using Bracket IDE in that the "mask-image" property is not working. Perhaps it appearing as red color so I think it's not working but the same code working on Codepen etc and Stack Overflow too with correct display.

The edge transparent is not coming as expected due to mask-image property which is not working on Bracket IDE.

```css
nav {
  max-width: 960px;
  mask-image: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, #ffffff 25%, #ffffff 75%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 60px 0;
}

nav ul {
  text-align: center;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #7FFFD4 0%, #7FFFD4 25%, #7FFFD4 75%, #7FFFD4 100%);
  box-shadow: 0 0 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), inset 0 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left:80px;
}

nav ul li a {
  padding: 18px;
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  text-transform:uppercase;
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), inset 0 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
  color: rgba(0, 35, 122, 0.7);
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">About</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Services</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

I have attached screenshots.

This is the expected one:

[image: This is the expected one]

This is bracket, why it displaying mask-image as red:

[image: This is bracket, why it displaying mask-image as red]

This is my output:

[image: This is my output]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, it was  live-preview error but while opening directly with any browser, it works as expected.

Comment: You can delete a question